# Dynamically Reconfigure AMCL Params

Tags: ros-kinetic, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How is it possible to dynamically reconfigure AMCL params with the dynamic_reconfigure package? AMCL does not have a set_params service so the reconfigure node always times out waiting for it to be advertised and accomplishes nothing.

I hope this is a simple question to answer, thanks so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328315/dynamically-reconfigure-amcl-params/) by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 977 on 2019-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> How is it possible to dynamically reconfigure AMCL params with the dynamic_reconfigure package?

rqt_reconfigure  succeeds former dynamic_reconfigure's GUI.
Here is how to reconfigure AMCL using rqt_reconfigure's graphical user interface:

Start AMCL and pass the laser scans topic and robot base_frame_id as parameters.
In my case it is:

```
$ rosrun amcl amcl scan:=/kobuki/laser/scan base_frame_id:=/base_footprint
```

Or create an amcl launch file and use that launch file to start the amcl node.

Then launch rqt_reconfigure:

```
$ rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure
```

You will see the screen as follows:

[image: image description]

Click on **amcl** on the left side panel.

To modify the parameters on the fly, click and drag any of the sliders.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) with karma: 500 on 2020-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1